# C++ nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object

Tags: c++

First things first, I think it will make more sense to see my code. Header:

```
#include <vector>
#include "GUIItem.h"

class WindowManager
{
private:
    static WindowManager* s_wndmgr; //A singleton maintains a pointer to itself as a class variable
    std::vector<GUIItem*> m_guilist; //storage for gui item
//...

public:
    static void Create();
    static void Destroy();
    static inline WindowManager* Get()
    {
        return s_wndmgr;
    }
    static void addItem(GUIItem *newGUIItem);
};
```

And the class:

```
#include "WindowManager.h"
#include "GUIButton.h"

WindowManager* WindowManager::s_wndmgr = NULL;

WindowManager::WindowManager()
{
    s_wndmgr = NULL;
}

WindowManager::~WindowManager()
{
    //Cleanup other stuff if necessary

    delete s_wndmgr;
}

void WindowManager::Create()
{
    if ( !s_wndmgr ) s_wndmgr = new WindowManager();
    GUIButton *m_btn1 = new GUIButton();
    addItem(m_btn1);    
}

void WindowManager::Destroy()
{
    if ( s_wndmgr ) delete s_wndmgr;
}

void WindowManager::addItem(GUIItem * newGUIItem)
{
    m_guilist.push_back(newGUIItem);
}
```

Hopefully it makes some kind of sense. I'm trying to create a simple gui framework from scratch in OpenGL and this is a simple window manager. My issue is with `m_guilist` which should be accessible so that new GUIItems can be added to it such as happens in `Create` (GUIItem being a base class from which others inherit, such as GUIButton).

In this case I'm using `addItem` in order to append items to the list but I'm running into the `a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object` error regarding the line inside `addItem`. I'm a little confused as to why this is the case. I understand that making `addItem` static is the reason for this error, but that was done in order for it to be called from within `Create`. Is there a way around this?

Sorry, this is quite the poor question and my grasp of C++ isn't great yet though I'm getting there. Any thoughts on this? Something tells me I'd be better to leave the `Create` function alone and create another nonstatic function to create my GUIItems and add them to the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addItem` is a `static` function, which does not not operate on any instance of `WindowManager`. It can not access `m_guilist`, which is non-static without an instance.

Maybe you just want:

```
Get()->m_guilist.push_back(newGUIItem);
```

But you're starting to make the interface `static`, that's kind of hybrid. It's usually that `addItem` is non-static and you call it with the instance you acquire by `WindowManager::Get()`.

Yet, `WindowManager` doesn't have inaccessible or deleted constructor to qualify as a singleton class. [Ways to implement a Singleton design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern).

Comment: lol he's not going to able to understand this. @Jamie4840 Just add "static" to your m_guilist variable

Comment: I do understand this thanks. The only reason `addItem` is static is otherwise it can't be accessed by `Create`, there'll be a similar error. I have tried making `m_guilist` static but I get an error about an unresolved external symbol relating to `static std::vector<GUIItem*>`